# Direct path return or direct access to VMs behind Azure LB

Tags: azure, load-balancing

We have an interesting problem that is proving a bit tricky to come up with a good solution for in the Azure environment.  Essentially, we have a software service that runs on Linux (using CentOS VMs) that listens for a TCP connection on a specific port (a "control" channel) and then asks the client to connect to a specific UDP port (a "data" channel).  We'd like this to run in a load balanced environment BUT the Azure LB doesn't allow any kind of direct access to the VMs behind the LB.

I've tried the "direct return path" option on a LB set but that doesn't seem to work with Linux VMs (no traffic ever makes it up the stack because the traffic is directed to the VIP which the VM has no knowledge of).

The only option I can think of is to use traffic manager but it seems rather crude for this application (TM isn't crude, it is to solve this problem with just DNS redirection).

There's a couple of examples I've come across but they all talk about http redirection and using IIS which isn't really an option here with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is a preview of [instance-level public IP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690118.aspx) addresses which allows direct access to VMs in Azure. Currently, there is a limit of two instance-level public IP addresses per subscription.